# My map works in jsfiddle but not in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LzezLgtz/74/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
#map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
.controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 32px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-left: 12px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
    border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
    font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4d90fe;
    padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
    width: 345px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<script>



function initialize() {


  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.112, -86.2907);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

        alert(event.latLng);
      });

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }

    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the html that's not working: https://www.cootel.com.ni/cootel/wp-content/files/mapas/mapa-nicaragua.html

I've tried this on my local computer and I get the same result. It only works in jsfiddle.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `but not in browser` wha?

Comment: do you have an API key? (not required in jsfiddle, required on your site unless you had maps before 22 july 2016)

Comment: I do have an Api Key

Answer (score 0):

Change you css from

```
#map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

to

```
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

in your html page.

Comment: Already tried that.. still doesnt work.

https://www.cootel.com.ni/cootel/wp-content/files/mapas/mapa-nicaragua.html

Comment: Hey, This page is showing errors in console

1) The page at 'https://www.cootel.com.ni/cootel/wp-content/files/mapas/mapa-nicaragua.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

2) Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined